# How to increase screen lock timeout in CentOS 7 image running in VMWare workstation

Tags: vmware-workstation, centos-7

I am running CentOS 7 64 bit in my VMWare worstation Pro 15 installed in Windows 10 host OS. The guest CentOS keeps getting screen locked when I am idle for sometime, doing work in my host Windows OS. I am searching for the exact setting that I might add in my .vmx file or any other place, which will increase my CentOS guest OS screen timeout value.

Comment: Thanks @davidbaumann for the solution. Silly of me not to think of this! ;) I still see a screensaver on remaining idle in guest, but not having to unlock it with my password every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to disable this in your guest.

If you are not using your virtual machine, it acts like a usual pc which no mouse and keyboard interaction.

It depends on your Desktop Environment, how to do that.